# Java generics, using <? extends Superclass>, clarification needed

Tags: java, generics

Suppose

```
    A extends X
```

You need to perform some operation on object either A. Method performing the operation may be:

```
    public void doMagic(List<? extends X> e)
```

Alternatively, you may chose to call it

```
    public void doMagic2(List<X> e)
```

You ask for magic to be done by:

```
    List<X> listOfA = new ArrayList<X>();
    listOfA.add(new A());

    C c = new C();
    c.doMagic(listOfA);   // works as expected
    c.doMagic2(listOfA);  // works as expected
```

Can you describe why one approach is preferred over another and when it should be used please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case of `List<X>` as you can guess, it would work with objects of type `X` only.

In case of `List<? extends X>`, it would accept a list of `X` and all the sub-classes of `X` or all the implementations of `X` if `X` was an `interface`.

The benefits of one over the other, well, `? extends X` would allow you to take care of situation when you want to handle all sorts of different sub classes.

An example would be a function that calculates, say, size in bytes of files:

```
public int getTotalSizeInBytes(List<? extends File> files) {
...
}
```

Now this function can go about calculating the size regardless of the file type which can be `plainTextFile`, `excelFile`, `wordFile`, `databaseFile` etc.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you had something like this:

```
    List<A> listOfA = new ArrayList<A>();
    listOfA.add(new A());
```

You would be able to call `doMagic()`, but you would not be able to call `doMagic2()`. If you want your method only to deal with `X` objects and not ever any of its child classes, use `List<X>`. However, if your method wanted to deal with any kind of `X` objects, not caring if it was actually a child class, use `List<? extends X>`